# Python - Setting ylim with matplotlib results in additional unwanted ytick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, wavelet-transform

I have an error where setting the yaxis limits (e.g. `ax1.set_ylim(2,8)`) is causing an additional set of ytick labels to appear. Here's a reproducible example of a wavelet power spectrum plot.

```
import numpy as np
from wavelets import WaveletAnalysis
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

# normalisation function
def normalize(data, a, b):
    return [(b-a)*(((x-data.min())/(data.max()-data.min())))+a for x in data]

# create example data
np.random.seed(420)
x = np.random.rand(23)
time = np.asarray(range(1994,2017,1))

# Wavelet analysis
dt = 1
wa = WaveletAnalysis(x, time=time, dt=dt)
# wavelet power spectrum
power = wa.wavelet_power
# normalise (unitless metric)
power = normalize(power, -5, 5)
# scales 
scales = wa.scales
# associated time vector
t = wa.time

# plot
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,3))
T, S = np.meshgrid(t, scales)
plt.contourf(T, S, power, list(range(-5, 6, 1)), cmap='plasma')
cbar = plt.colorbar(ticks=[-5, 0, 5])
cbar.set_label('Wavelet Power Spectrum', rotation=270, labelpad=16)
ax1.set_yscale('log')

ax1.set_ylim(2,8) # This is the line that is causing the issue

ax1.set_yticks([2, 4, 8])
ax1.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
ax1.set_ylabel('Log Transformed Period (years)', labelpad=16)
plt.xticks(np.arange(1994, 2017, step=2))
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
# line CI
C, S2 = wa.coi
plt.plot(C, S2, '--', color='grey', alpha=1)

plt.show()
```

Resulting plot when the `ax1.set_ylim(2,8)` is included, notice the unwanted ytick labels (e.g. `2 x 10^0` etc.):

[image: Example of error]

Resulting plot when the `# ax1.set_ylim(2,8)` is commented out:

[image: Example with no error]

How can I set the limits for the yaxis and avoid these additional tick labels appearing? Thanks!

Comment: Those ticklabels are minor ticklabels. You can turn them off if you like. There are many questions about this already, could you please find those and mark this as duplicate?

Comment: Thank you @Ernest. Easy when you know what to search for. `plt.minorticks_off()` fixed the issue. Will mark this question as a duplicate.